# How to directly make a phone call with private API CTCallDial()?

Tags: jailbreak

in Iphone,How to directly make a phone call  with private API CTCallDial()?  Mainly because I don't know the specific parameters of CTCallDial.

Comment: same question for me, make a call directly without launching the phone app. then end it from within my app. (using private API is fine for me)

Answer (score 5):

1) Link against CoreTelephony.framework

2) Define like

```
extern "C" id CTCallDial(NSString * number);
```

and use like:

```
CTCallDial(@"0123456789");
```

(returns the CTCallRef created, can be safely casted to id (CTCall *))

Comment: I tried it on iOS8, but its not performing any activity to dial. Will it work only on Jailbreak phones or normal phones as well? Do I have to enable anything like entitlements etc?

Comment: Yes, the above is tested from within SpringBoard process on a jailbroken iPhone, which has all the entitlements for making calls. Your app will need entitlements, probably com.apple.private.icfcallserver and/or com.apple.private.communicationsfilter, those appear the most related.