# Making a faux iPhone dialer

Tags: ios, contacts

I want to make a joke application for a friend (not for general sale) that looks exactly like the iOS Phone application but so that whatever number is dialled into the application it appears to dial that number but actually dials a preset number in the background.
The way I figured to do it would be through the following:

- User enters a number and hits the call button
- Save the number entered as a contact's name and programmatically set the number of that contact as the preset number
- Get the application to ring the preset number, to which it would switch over to the real iOS phone application and dial, but with it being a saved number in the contacts it will display the name, which is the number entered by the user.
- Delete that contact upon re-opening the application as for it to not ask which number to dial the next time.

This is the only way that I can think of pulling this off, but it seems like it will look unconvincing; especially when it switches over to the real Phone application. Can anyone think of a better way? Such as calling from within the application?
I wouldn't usually take junk requests like this but it made me curious as to pull it off best.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to publish this, then there is no reason why you shouldn't use private apis. See this answer ([How to directly make a phone call with private API CTCallDial()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207042/how-to-directly-make-a-phone-call-with-private-api-ctcalldial))

Comment: I've just tried this out and it appears that it's not working. Quick Google says they stopped it from working in iOS7.. :/

Comment: There may still be a way to do it if you search through the header files for CoreTelephony.